# IIS FTP Site : Username with special chars

Tags: ftp, authentication, iis, username, iis-8

Using IIS 10, i want to **connect to my FTP Site** :

- My Windows 10 is called `gaia` (this is the hostname).
- I've created two users wich is called `john`, and `clément`
  (the second on have a special char (diacritics)).
- I've added the two users to the Explorer Security Permission Folder
- I've added the two users into the IIS FTP Authorization Rules

On my Windows 10, when I go to `ftp://gaia`, an **authentication modal** want me to log-in :

1. If I log-in using `john` and password, **I'm rejected**
2. If I log-in using `gaia\john` and password, **I'm connected**
3. If i log-in using `clément` and password, **I'm rejected**
4. If I log-in using `gaia\clément` and password, **I'm rejected**

I have two questions :

- Why do I **have to specify the hostname and backslash** (`gaia\`) before the username to make it Work? Is there a way to make it optionnal?
- Why does the user `clément` never work? It's because of the special char `é`? Is there a way to make it work?

Here is the ISS Trace (`C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\FTPSVC2\u_ex160612.log`) :

> ```
> 2016-06-12 14:03:49 ::1 - ::1 21 USER gaia\clÃ©ment 331 0 0 2c4e89ae-2fba-4511-8665-25cd99ad4fc2 -
> 2016-06-12 14:03:49 ::1 - ::1 21 PASS *** 530 1326 41 2c4e89ae-2fba-4511-8665-25cd99ad4fc2 -
> 2016-06-12 14:03:49 ::1 - ::1 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 0 0 2c4e89ae-2fba-4511-8665-25cd99ad4fc2 -
> 2016-06-12 14:03:49 ::1 - ::1 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 fc60b61c-83a2-46c5-a980-db632fd37210 -
> 2016-06-12 15:31:17 ::1 - ::1 21 USER gaia\john 331 0 0 db1b9e5b-2fdb-4984-85c7-d51658831828 -
> 2016-06-12 15:31:17 ::1 gaia\john ::1 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 db1b9e5b-2fdb-4984-85c7-d51658831828 /
> 2016-06-12 15:31:17 ::1 gaia\john ::1 21 CWD / 250 0 0 db1b9e5b-2fdb-4984-85c7-d51658831828 /
> 2016-06-12 15:31:17 ::1 gaia\john ::1 21 TYPE A 200 0 0 db1b9e5b-2fdb-4984-85c7-d51658831828 -
> 2016-06-12 15:31:17 ::1 gaia\john ::1 21 EPSV - 229 0 0 db1b9e5b-2fdb-4984-85c7-d51658831828 -
> ```

Thanks for help :-) !

Comment: From memory there's an option to use a default domain to login, might want to investigate that.

Comment: is `Allow UTF-8`set to true in your ftp sites configuration?

Comment: **MichaelNancarrow :** Indeed, When i select my FTP Site > Home View > FTP Authentication > Right-click to Basic Authentication > Naming a default Domain. It's done, restarted, but still require specify domain on log-in.
/
**SimonS :** Yes, When i select my FTP Site > Pane View > Advanced parameters, i can see "Allow UTF8 : Yes". Maybe is the FTP Client wich don't support diacritics ?